# Write information from GUI to Excel Worksheet

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

I am working on a GUI app using TKinter, and the information entered by the user needs to then write to a excel document using Openpyxl. For now, I am trying to get the name chosen from the eng_lst option menu and write that name to cell A3 of Contacts sheet of GatewayUpgrade2.xlsx workbook. How can this be done? Thank you.

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1559, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: UpdateSheet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'


from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import openpyxl


class Application(Frame):


    """GUI app to automate CR creation"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        """Initialize the Frame"""
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()




    def create_widgets(self):
        #create instruction label and Entry widget
        eng_font=('Lucida Grande', 11)
        #CR Number Entry Box
        self.cr_label = Label(self, text="CR Number: ", font=eng_font)
        self.cr_label.grid(row=0, sticky = E)
        self.cr_ent = Entry(self)
        self.cr_ent.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)


        #create Submit button
        self.submit_bttn = Button(self, text = "Submit", command = self.UpdateSheet).grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)

        #Engineer Selection
        self.eng_name = Label(self, text="Select Engineer: ", font=eng_font).grid(row=3, sticky=E)
        variable=StringVar(self)
        variable.set("")
        eng_lst=OptionMenu(self, variable, 'Johnson, Bob', 'Doe, John', 'Doe, Jane')
        eng_lst.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

        #CR Start Date & Time
        self.date_lbl=Label(self, text="CR Start Date & Time", font=eng_font).grid(row=5,sticky=E)
        self.date_ent=Entry(self).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=E)
        self.duration_lbl=Label(self, text="Change Duration", font=eng_font).grid(row=6, sticky=E)
        self.duration_ent = Entry(self).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=E)

        #CR Type Selection
        self.cr_type_lbl = Label(self, text = 'CR Type', font = eng_font).grid(row=8, sticky=E)
        variableType=StringVar(self)
        variableType.set("")
        cr_type=OptionMenu(self, variableType, 'Gateway Upgrade', 'NIC Replacement', 'Interface Errors', 'Decomm', 'Failover')
        cr_type.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W)

    def UpdateSheet(self, value):
            wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('GatewayUpgrade2.xlsx')
            wb.get_sheet_by_name('Contacts')
            eng_name = value
            wb['A3'] = eng_name








#main
root=Tk()
root.title("CR Creation Tool")
root.geometry("400x250")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpdateSheet needs an input value called value. But for your submit button you don't specify, what this input value should be. So change the line

```
self.submit_bttn = Button(self, text = "Submit", command = self.UpdateSheet).grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)
```

to

```
value = ... specify the value here
self.submit_bttn = Button(self, text = "Submit", command = lambda: self.UpdateSheet(value)).grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)
```

Comment: Excellent, really appreciate your help!